# crop marks don't show up on pages with included pdf on full page

Tags: crop, bleed

I added some crop marks using the `crop` package. They show up on every page, except on these with full-page pdf included (with width set to A4+bleed). On those pages they are behind the pdf. Is there some way to add the crop marks on top of the pdfpages?

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=1.5cm,
    bottom=1.5cm,
    includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\newcommand{\printingPaperWidth}{216mm}
\newcommand{\printingPaperHeight}{303mm}

\usepackage[
width=21.6truecm, height=30.3truecm,
noinfo,
cam,
center]{crop}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
% A4 pdf, scaled to fill bleed. Crop marks dont show up.
\includepdf[pages=-,width=\printingPaperWidth,pagecommand={}]{some.pdf}

\clearpage
Here they are.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do get crop marks on the pages with the included pas. Does your included pdf has a transparent background or solid color?

Comment: @user190633, my guess is no. Try using `example-image.pdf` and stretch it to the full page.

Comment: @DavidPurton That's why I am wondering. It works with `example-image-a4`. If this is indeed the cause of the problem, one could simply remove the background.

Comment: @user190633, except if they are scanned bitmaps, or something like that.

Comment: Is bleed actually needed for these pages? If not, you could just crop them to your trim box.

Comment: @DavidPurton Most image processing software can do color to alpha :)

Comment: @user190633, but there is no need for bleed with a transparent background. So if bleed is required, you will *need* the background a solid colour.

Comment: @user190633, and besides, it would be much easier to add the crop marks to the existing PDF than remove a background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this works. I just adjust `\CROP@shiplist` to output main shipout box at 0pt height then output the crop marks last.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=1.5cm,    
    bottom=1.5cm,
    includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\newcommand{\printingPaperWidth}{216mm}
\newcommand{\printingPaperHeight}{303mm}

\usepackage[
width=21.6truecm, height=30.3truecm,
noinfo,
cam,
center]{crop}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\CROP@shiplist{%
    \lineskip\z@
    \lineskiplimit\z@
    \baselineskip\z@
    \vbox to 0pt{\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}%
    \CROP@kernel
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% A4 pdf, scaled to fill bleed. Crop marks dont show up.
\includepdf[%
  pages=-, width=\printingPaperWidth, height=\printingPaperHeight,
  ]{example-image.pdf}

\clearpage
Here they are.
\end{document}
```

Comment: On the MWE, it works fine (after deleting aux, toc files), but on my main document, I get only white pages with crop marks. I suspect that the order is the reason why it doesn't work, but I could figure it out.

Comment: @dasch, did you get it working? If you can produce a minimal example that fails, you could try asking another question.

Comment: I just figured it out. I had to remove `\usepackage{pagecolor}`. I don't know how this package is related, but this is the cause.

Comment: @dasch, `pagecolor` probably also messes with the shipout box. A similar technique could probably still be made to work if needed.

Comment: the package wasn't needed anyway, it was legacy code when I played around with making the whole page black and the text white. Thank you!